# Oil Drill's Equation of Motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find equation of motion for the following system:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d236l.jpg
Parameters of the system are $J_T, J_B, \theta_T, \theta_B, T_f $.
I derived two equation, but i am not sure that is true.

For Table/Top:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
  \dot{\omega}_T(t)=-\frac{b}{J_T}\omega_T(t)-\bigg[\frac{k}{J_T}\theta_T(t)-\frac{k}{J_T}\theta_B(t)\bigg]+\frac{1}{J_T}T(t)
\end{equation}

For Bit/Bottom:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
  \dot{\omega}_B(t)=-\frac{b}{J_B}\omega_B(t)+\bigg[\frac{k}{J_B}\theta_T(t)-\frac{k}{J_T}\theta_B(t)\bigg]-\frac{1}{J_B}T_f(t)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the kinetic energy

$$
E = \frac 12 J_B\omega_B^2+\frac 12 J_T\omega_b^T+\frac 12 k(\theta_B-\theta_T)^2
$$

the motion equations are derived according Euler-Lagrange

$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial \theta}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial E}{\partial\omega} = \tau
$$

so we have

$$
k(\theta_B-\theta_T)+J_B\dot\omega_B + b\omega_B = -T_f\\
-k(\theta_B-\theta_T)+J_T\dot\omega_T + b\omega_T = T
$$

Here $\dot\omega = \ddot\theta$

Comment: This verifies my result. Thank you so much.